# ExecutorService that scales threads then queues tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Is there an `ExecutorService` implementation that behaves like a thread pool with the following characteristics?

1. There are always at least X active threads.
2. If a task is submitted and all active threads are busy, a new thread is started, up to Y threads.
3. If a task is submitted and all Y threads are busy, the task is queued.
4. If no new tasks are submitted, the pool scales back down to X active threads.

Pretty standard thread pooling behavior. You'd think that `ThreadPoolExecutor` would handle this, but

```java
executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    2, 10, // min/max threads
    60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, // time of inactivity before scaling back
    new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>()); // task queue
```

will throw an exception if more than 10 tasks are submitted. Switching to a `LinkedBlockingQueue` will never scale up past the two minimum threads, unless you limit the size like `new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20)`, in which case there will be two threads handling 1-20 tasks, 2-10 threads handling 21-30 tasks, and an exception for more than 30 tasks. Not pretty. A fixed thread pool, meanwhile, will never scale down inactive threads.

So, to get what I'm after, can I use a different kind of `BlockingQueue` or fiddle with some other setting I've missed? Is there another `ExceutorService` implementation that is better suited (which?), or am I better off rolling my own by overriding the `execute()` method of `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

Comment: I don't think a few inactive threads would do much harm ?

Comment: I too do not understand your concern about inactive threads. Afaik, they sit there resting with virtually no overhead cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. About the best you can do with what is in the jre is to effectively not have a thread floor, only a ceiling. This can be accomplished by [allowing core threads to timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut-boolean-).

```
ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 60, TimeUnit.Seconds, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
tpe.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

Because the core size is 10, a new thread will be started when a task is submitted until 10 threads are active. After that, tasks will queue in the LinkedBlockingQueue. If a thread has been inactive for 60 seconds it will terminate.

The behavior you want is possible by writing a class implementing both BlockingQueue and RejectedExecutionHandler, which checks the ThreadPoolExecutors current state before determining if the task should be added to the queue or rejected.

Comment: This was just what I needed, although I used a limited-size ArrayBlockingQueue instead. I'd add that you can use [ExecutorService.prestartAllCoreThreads()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartAllCoreThreads()) and tune your idle-timeout to mimic "always-on" core thread behavior, if you anticipate a certain minimum load.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `SynchronousQueue` has essentially size of zero and due to that when you submit more than 10 tasks (max pool size) the rejection policy kicks in and task gets rejected. Also for every submitted task it gets a thread and makes use of it.

When you use `LinkedBlockingQueue`with size 20, if core size has been reached and there is no idle thread it will queue the task. They will keep on queuing unless queue is full and in that case it will create a new thread to be used for new task. When pool size reaches max then rejection policy comes in for any new submission.

You want that whenever a task is submitted and all the threads in core (core-size) are busy your task should get a new thread rather than waiting in queue which I think is not possible.

Comment: @Brett you are right I just made a mistake. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, maxPoolSize, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
    tpe.setRejectedExecutionHandler((
            Runnable r,
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor) -> {
        // this will block if the queue is full but not until the sun will rise in the west!
            try {
                if(!executor.getQueue().offer(r, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)){
                    throw new RejectedExecutionException("Will not wait infinitely for offer runnable to ThreadPoolExecutor");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RejectedExecutionException("Unable to put runnable to queue", e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Submitting a `Runnable` directly to the executor's internal queue seems inadvisable. Per the documentation: "Method `getQueue()` allows access to the work queue for purposes of monitoring and debugging. Use of this method for any other purpose is strongly discouraged."